# Spring Boot 3 App with Swagger cannot deployed with AWS (Severe Issue)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem to deploy my **Spring Boot 3** with **Swagger** to **AWS**.

After creating the environment from **elastic beanstalk** and defining **jar** file of the project, I complete the process.

I get this message "**Severe**" for the instance after waiting a certain of time.

I also changed `server.port= 5000` and define `SERVER_PORT 5000` for the environment of the software configuration but nothing changed.

Here is the image shown below

[image: Link]

Here is the health overview information shown below.

```
Severe

Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (12.0 requests/min) to determine application health. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

How can I fix the issue?

The **local URL** is `http://localhost:5000/swagger-ui/index.html`

Here is the **link** showing **logs** : [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ObPKRXvlGmNMeCVQIF8-r_uSV-6W2R_Q/view?usp=share_link)

Here is the **repo** : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/DepremApi)

Comment: Are there any logs? If so, can you share them?

Comment: your beanstalk link to the logs is not accessible to public

Comment: @SathyajithBhat I revised the link. Can you look through it?

Comment: @dan1st I shared the logs through the link

Comment: Have you tried accessing the URL through the standard http/https port? I remember that beanstalk puts a nginx server in front of the application, so the port you configure for the application remains internal, and the exposed one is the nginx port.

Comment: @SantiagoMedina My issue is that the app cannot be deployed as I get "severe" issue even if I defined SERVER_PORT as 5000 in its environment.

Comment: Understood. I see many requests to / in your logs made by ELB-HealthChecker with response 404. Seems that EB performs a GET to your base path expecting a 200 to consider your application as healthy deployed, but gets 404. Try implementing that response programmatically, or putting a index.html under src/main/resources/static, or configuring EB to do the health check against a different URL.

Comment: @SantiagoMedina I shared the causes. Even if I tried to deploy it many times with selecting Java and coretto 17,11 and 8, I still got the same issue. There is no issue when I run this command `mvn clean install` as I get a message as `Build Success`

Comment: Yes, I know your application builds OK, and starts OK. But ELB health checker expects a 200 OK response when sending a GET to your base path, but the application don't provide any response on that path (404-not found). You have only a controller listening to /api/.., but nothing on the root. Then ELB believe it's not up. That's why I suggested adding a response through a home static page (index.html), or programmatically with a controller, or changing the EB health check configuration to check a different path.

Comment: @SantiagoMedina How can I define the root programmatically with a controller instead of creating a static page (index.html)?

Comment: Change (a) for @
(a)RestController
public class HealthController {

    (a)GetMapping
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "Application is UP";
    }
}

Comment: You could also use the spring boot actuator module, that implements a health endpoint, but not in the root, so you would need to change the ELB config to check the health in the actuator path (/actuator/health)

Comment: @SantiagoMedina What should I do after adding its dependency?

Comment: @SantiagoMedina I tried to define endpoints in the browser and it work but there is a problem in root path. How can I fix it? How can I define it in configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251787/discussion-between-santiago-medina-and-s-n).