# 504 Gateway Time-out on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using aws beanstalk to launch a laravel api backend and now i am getting this error: 504 Gateway Time-out

i think it has something to do with the load balancer, The environment health is severe. Please Help

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (12.0 requests/min) to determine application health. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.

I have tried the keep alive settings by i think the solution lies on the Target groups. Please give a solution to this

Comment: This looks similar as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600066/aws-elastic-beanstalk-100-0-of-the-requests-are-erroring-with-http-4xx?rq=2